# How to style VideoJS with Next.js

Tags: css, import, next.js, video.js, react-component

I am building a react video component based on **VideoJS** and I used to style VideoJS player using a stylesheet of mine but since I import it as recommended by **Next.js** documentation, some class targeting seem not to work properly and my custom CSS does not apply to `.video-js` css components.

This *works*:

```css
.video {
    font-family: 'Inter', -apple-system, Helvetica;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.video *:before {
    text-shadow:  1px 1px 7px rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.5);
}
```

This *doesn't work*:

```css
/* Big play button */
.video .vjs-big-play-button {
    height: 2em;
    width: 2em;
    font-size: 5em;
    line-height: 2em;
    border: none !important;
    border-radius: 9999px;
}
```

My **VideoPlayer component**:

```js
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import videojs from 'video.js';
import 'video.js/dist/video-js.css'
import styles from '../styles/video-player.module.css';

function VideoPlayer(props) {
    const [videoEl, setVideoEl] = useState(null);
    const onVideo = useCallback((el) => {
        setVideoEl(el)
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (videoEl == null) return
        const player = videojs(videoEl, props)
        return () => {
            player.dispose()
        }
    }, [props, videoEl])

    return (
        <div data-vjs-player>
            <video className={`video-js ${styles.video} vjs-big-play-centered`} ref={onVideo}/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default VideoPlayer;
```

As I mentioned, I used to style video.js player this way and it always worked perfectly until I switched to Next.js. Even stranger, the `.video` class doesn't appear in the browser's developer tools when inspecting the page.

Is there a way I could apply my custom styling properly with Next.js ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after looking for a workaround, I found that styling my custom video component in my **global.scss** file would actually work. I don't particularly know why specifically but here's how you can do:

This is my **global.scss** file:

```css
/* Base styling */
/* .class { ... } */

/* VideoJS styling -> */
.video-js.video {

    * {
        & :before {
            text-shadow:  1px 1px 7px rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.5);
        }
    }

    &:hover {
        .vjs-big-play-button {
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
        }
    }

    .vjs-big-play-button {
        height: initial;
        width: initial;
        font-size: 5em;
        line-height: 6.15rem;
        padding: 1em;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 9999px;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);

        & :before {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

    }

    .vjs-control-bar {
        width: 90%;
        min-height: 5em;
        margin: 2rem auto;
        padding: 0 1em;
        border-radius: 1em;
    }
}
```

So you won't have to import '../styles/video-player/module.scss' in VideoPlayer React component

Comment: To clarify, you need to overwrite the styles from your global CSS file because you're targeting global classes from Video.js CSS. Using them inside a CSS modules file would scope the classes you use there.

Comment: It doesn't work even after putting in global css

Comment: You probably missed something as it truly works in my case. You could look for a way to check if your global.css file works fine. Next.js documentation may help you: https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/assets-metadata-css